# AddressBookExternalChangeCallback not call with iPhone 5 iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

My app load contacts from the native contacts on my iPhone, into my app when I edit contact I use the follow function to refresh contacts, and the action edit can update into contacts list of my app.

```
void AddressBookExternalChangeCallback (
                                    ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
                                    CFDictionaryRef info,
                                    void *context
                                    )
{
    [(__bridge ContactsManager*)context refreshContacts];
}
```

The problem is this function had NOT CALL when I run on iPhone 5(iOS 7) device. However, with iOS 7 on iPod touch or iPhone 4s this function had call. Please help me to find out the root cause. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody can answer this question? and nobody ever faced with this problem? please help me if anyone can solve this problem.Thanks again.